# How do I set MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin and trying to run one of my apps in the iOS simulator but I am getting this error:

```
2015-10-07 12:38:02.715 MolinaCoding1iOS[1550:54337] Unhandled managed exception:
Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false. (System.Exception)
```

How do I actually ignore this condition? If I should not ignore this...then what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like it is blowing up when trying to load a UIImage from file.  Does the file exist, do you have the path and naming correct, etc?

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes @MarioGalván. This is an error that happens when Xamarin is looking for a image on the native layer that is null. You are missing an image somewhere and this is difficult to debug

Comment: In my case I had an image set like this: Icon = "Search.png"; But the image name was search.png. LOWERCASE. This worked fine until now...

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem solved by running "Clean" on my project (using Visual Studio). Right Click your project and select "Clean". Run the application afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore by adding the below statement just before you use that class/ method.

```
ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure = false;
```